# SQL Syntax error with multiple sub query joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help!

I'm getting syntax errors on part of my query and can't figure out what's wrong. Intellisense doesn't work on the database I'm using. I have tried to enclose the sub-queries with brackets but this still throws up a syntax error. Can anyone spot the problem please? I assume it's a missing bracket or something but I have been unable to find anything on the syntax of subqueries.

Note that what I'm trying to do is to convert an existing MS Access report into SQL which is proving quite difficult due to the sheer amount of queries embedded into each other to produce the data. Anything prepended with 'qry' is a reference to something in Access. This query is against a database used to track staff entry/exit from doors and is used for attendance reporting. Unfortunately as it's not an in-house system I don't have access to the database schema so am struggling to build a query myself. I can post the full thing but without context it may not make much sense? For now I will post part of the query.

The errors I'm getting:

```
>Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
>Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'RIGHT'.
>Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 27
>Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'RIGHT'.
>Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 34
>Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.
```

Part of the SQL query below. Note that line 21 is where the first 'RIGHT JOIN' is.

```
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT vw_ReportQuery.UserID
        ,vw_ReportQuery.[6000UserName]
        ,vw_ReportQuery.[6007EventTime]
        ,CAST([6007EventTime] AS DATETIME) AS SDate
        ,DatePart(HOUR, [6007EventTIme]) AS hoursBetween
        ,vw_ReportQuery.[6002DoorName]
    FROM vw_ReportQuery
    WHERE (
            ((vw_ReportQuery.[6000UserName]) = 'Smith, Jon')
            AND (
                (vw_ReportQuery.[6007EventTime]) >= '1/1/2016 00:00:00'
                AND (vw_ReportQuery.[6007EventTime]) <= '1/30/2016 00:00:00'
                )
            AND (
                (DatePart(Hour, [6007EventTIme])) BETWEEN 12
                    AND 14
                )
            AND (
                (vw_ReportQuery.[6002DoorName]) LIKE 'Gnd floor Rear Goods Door (out)'
                OR (vw_ReportQuery.[6002DoorName]) LIKE 'Gnd flr Staff Entrance (out)'
                OR (vw_ReportQuery.[6002DoorName]) LIKE 'Gnd flr Sub-let entrance (out)'
                OR (
                    (vw_ReportQuery.[6002DoorName]) LIKE 'Gnd floor Rear Goods Door (in)'
                    OR (vw_ReportQuery.[6002DoorName]) LIKE 'Gnd flr Staff Entrance (in)'
                    OR (vw_ReportQuery.[6002DoorName]) LIKE 'Gnd flr Sub-let entrance (in)'
                    )
                )
            )
    ) AS qryTestSelectedLunchPeriodHas_1 ON qryTestSelectedLunchPeriodHas.SDate = qryTestSelectedLunchPeriodHas_1.SDate
GROUP BY qryTestSelectedLunchPeriodHas.UserID
    ,qryTestSelectedLunchPeriodHas.[6000UserName]
    ,qryTestSelectedLunchPeriodHas.SDate ) -- as qryTestLunchPeriodHasFinal 
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT vw_ReportQuery.UserID
        ,vw_ReportQuery.[6000UserName]
        ,vw_ReportQuery.[6007EventTime]
        ,Cast([6007EventTime] AS DATETIME) AS SDate
    FROM vw_ReportQuery
    WHERE (
            ((vw_ReportQuery.[6000UserName]) = 'Smith, Jon')
            AND (
                (vw_ReportQuery.[6007EventTime]) >= '1/1/2016 00:00:00'
                AND (vw_ReportQuery.[6007EventTime]) <= '1/30/2016 00:00:00'
                )
            )
    RIGHT JOIN (
        SELECT vw_ReportQuery.UserID
            ,vw_ReportQuery.[6000UserName]
            ,vw_ReportQuery.[6007EventTime]
            ,Cast([6007EventTime] AS DATETIME) AS SDate
        FROM vw_ReportQuery
        WHERE (
                ((vw_ReportQuery.[6000UserName]) = 'Smith, Jon')
                AND (
                    (vw_ReportQuery.[6007EventTime]) >= '1/1/2016 00:00:00'
                    AND (vw_ReportQuery.[6007EventTime]) <= '1/30/2016 00:00:00'
                    )
                )
        ) ON qrySelectedDatesAndUser.SDate = qrySelectedDatesAndUser_1.SDate
    ) ON qryTestLunchPeriodHasFinal.SDate = qrySelectedDatesAndUser.SDate
GROUP BY qrySelectedDatesAndUser.[6000UserName]
    ,qrySelectedDatesAndUser_1.SDate
    ,qryTestLunchPeriodHasFinal.First
    ,qryTestLunchPeriodHasFinal.Last
    ,qryTestLunchPeriodHasFinal.LunchPeriod
```

Comment: Perhaps you need table aliases?

Comment: I don't know where they go. Is it after each 'ON' or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your subquery alias commented out: `-- as qryTestLunchPeriodHasFinal`. And your other subqueries require aliases too. I'll bet that's your problem.

Additionally, instead of

```
OR (vw_ReportQuery.[6002DoorName]) LIKE 'Gnd flr Staff Entrance (out)'
OR (vw_ReportQuery.[6002DoorName]) LIKE 'Gnd flr Sub-let entrance (out)'
OR ....
```

You can simply do

```
OR vw_ReportQuery.[6002DoorName] IN ('Gnd flr Staff Entrance (out)', 'Gnd flr Sub-let entrance (out)', {etcetera})
```

Comment: I only commented that out as a test, it still doesn't work with it uncommented unfortunately. Thanks for the advice on using 'IN', anything to streamline this query would be useful. I've spent my time so far trying to ensure all sub queries work on their own (which they do) before putting them into the main query. I'd like to have more time to build it all myself but I don't